# How to Model a Matrix Table in Django

Tags: python, django, database-design

Modeling this simple table in Django ORM has plagued me for a while. My desired output is like the following.

```
                item_a  item_b  item_d  item_d 
-----------------------------------------------
item_a            0       2       4      2.2
item_b            1       0       3.5    0.3
item_c            2       4       0      2
item_d            3.2     1       1      0
```

My requirements:

- The relationship of the items is a matrix-like table like above.
- Each row of the above table can be edited.
- There must be also the possibility of adding new items.

The closest thing I've came across is using a `manytomany` relationship. But in this model my items have a relationship with themselves which makes it puzzling for me.

What is ***the*** way to model such a relationship in Django models?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information about what the underlying data model is here. What kinds of values are you trying to put into this matrix?

Comment: The underlying model is my question. I don't know how to model this representation. As for the values, they are floats.

Comment: No, I mean what is the actual thing you're trying to model. You have a matrix cell `(item_a, item_a) = 0` what does that mean? What is the problem you're trying to solve by making this? Or is it just the idea of doing this that you're wondering about? And is your desire to have an arbitrarily large `nxn` matrix of cells that can be edited through a web page? This can be definitely be done, it's just that knowing more about the problem can help direct the solution.

Comment: This table represents the dependency ratio between the items. item_a with item_a has zero dependencies. Values of the table can be adjusted or edited by an analyzer. These values are also used in another mathematical formula. I just can't wrap my head around the corresponding Django data model.

Comment: Can you start with how the dependency ratio is calculated? What does the data for that calculation look like?

Comment: The dependency is entered manually by some expert and it would be simply a float number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've got another model that defines what entries can appear as the rows/cols in the matrix:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class DependencyRatio(models.Model):
    col = models.ForeignKey(Items, related_name='column_item')
    row = models.ForeignKey(Items, related_name='row_item')
    value = models.FloatField()
```

Instead of representing a matrix as a square, you can also unroll it and represent it pairs of labels, along with a cell value.

Comment: brilliantly simple. Thank you.